# Alarmmanager will do the work?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am begginer developer in Android. I have few objects which are containing type "date". They are stored in database which is read at the start of program. Now I need to set up alarm for each of them at this date (I want to show notification to users). I wonder if alarmmanager is good for this purpose? Or is there something better? 
When I set up alarm once is it active even when I totally close my app? Or should I check at the start of the app if alarm is set and if not do it again?

Sorry for my English, 
With regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Alarm Manager is a fine was of doing what you need. The manager will continue to count to the next notification unless the device is switched off, if you wish to deal with this then you need to handle the Boot Receiver also.

One thing to remember (something I forget all the time) is that you need to add the AlarmReceiver class, whatever you use to display the notifications, to the Manifest so that it can be accessed by your intent in the Alarm Manager service.

Answer (score 0):

*I wonder if alarmmanager is good for this purpose?*

Yes

*When I set up alarm once is it active even when I totally close my app?* 
Yes. But you need to keep one thing in mind.

If you are using alarm manager, it will go off once your device turns off. 
To manage this either use broadcast receiver to handle device BOOT receiver and on this set your alarm manager again.

*Or should I check at the start of the app if alarm is set and if not do it again?*

Yes , This is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out the scheduling alarams sample](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

It has detailed instructions for scheduling alarms